# How to remove many folders from File History quickly?

Tags: windows-10, backup, file-history

Under Backup Options

[image]

there are dozens of folders, all subfolders of my main user folder.

[image]

I just want to backup the entire user folder and remove the listings for all the subfolders, but it takes ~2 minutes of [image: revolving dots] to delete each entry, so it would take a very long time to manually remove them all.  Is there somewhere else I can see a list of them and remove them?  Can I edit them out of the Registry?

Comment: Look in your USER's folder to see what you might wish to delete. Just because a folder is empty does not mean it should be deleted - probably not.

Comment: @John I don't want to delete folders.  I want to remove them from File History.  I don't want them backed up, in other words, because their parent folder is already in the list to be backed up.

Comment: I have the same issue, it's frustrating, I just reported it via Feedback hub: https://aka.ms/AAd8vwl or https://insider.windows.com/FeedbackHub/fb?contextid=58&feedbackid=a5a14281-75fe-4cd6-bb34-6afbd6594c01&form=1

Comment: @DaviddCeFreitas "Your account doesn't have access to this feedback"

Comment: You would need to use "Exclude these folders" in order to exclude the sub-folders, unfortunately one by one. You can't even use wildcards. A third-party backup utility might do better.

Comment: @user1251007 That looks promising